# How to reverse longitude/latitude of point in Postgis?

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, postgis

The points in Linestring in Postgis (imported from osm by osm2pgsql) is described by the order (longitude, latitude)

for example a Linestring in Munich Map

```
'LINESTRING(11.4068032 47.8580927,11.4067187 47.8580965)'
```

How could I reverse the order to normal (latitude, longitude) ? Is (longitude, latitude) very odd order ? Because I see popular Map API all use (latitude, longitude) order

Comment: If you think of longitude as your X coordinate, and latitude as the Y coordinate, the long,lat ordering makes a bit more sense as we tend to specify geometric points as X,Y, not Y,X. FWIW, SQL Server's geospatial features use the same ordering as PostGIS (SQL Server's geospatial functions seem to be derived from the geometric features, so the X,Y would make sense there) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [ST_FlipCoordinates](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html) to return a version of the given geometry with X and Y axis flipped.

Keep in mind, you generally want to keep the axis order (longitude, latitude), which is the correct axis order for PostGIS. Flipping it to (latitude, longitude) will generally break things.

Comment: `Keep in mind, you generally want to keep the axis order (longitude, latitude), which is the correct axis order for PostGIS` this is problematic though when you deal with actual CRS like EPSG:4326 which is defined as having axes order of latitude then longitude.  If I tell PostGIS I have data in [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) (lat/long) and it imports it assuming it's long/lat then that's a major issue and things do break.

Answer (score 0):

you could use below query:

`select st_askml(ST_FlipCoordinates(linestring)) as kml from table_name`